# Как сократить код в nparray при подвыборке с условием?

Tags: python, numpy

Сначала я выбираю первый столбец из `nparray`, затем из другого `nparray` по такому же индексу проверяю нули, и тогда беру в работу этот столбец.

Как одной строкой сделать выборку?

```
z = X4[:,0]
z0= z[y4==0]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
z0 = X4[y4==0, 0]
#              ^------------ выбираем первый (с индексом 0) столбец 
#       ^^^^^
#         |__________ выбираем строки по "булевой маске" - вектор булевых значений, 
#                     длина которого должна совпадать с числом строк в `X4`
```

PS сначала идет фильтрация по строкам (`axis=0`), затем по столбцам (`axis=1`)

Comment: А если вместо нуля единицу поставить z0 = X4[y4==0, 1] - то это выборка наоборот? Сначала по столбцам, а потом по строкам?

Comment: @svil, нет, сначала выбираем интересующие нас строки, потом из подвыборки строк выбираем нужные столбцы

Comment: Этот ноль из z = X4[:,0]

Comment: Догадалась тоже, пока отвечали. Спасибо за полный ответ.